# Table does not exist error despite I have it

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, entitymanager

when I use the entity manager commit I got the following error:
the entity title is exist and doesnt have any error what could be the reason for this error

Table/View 'S1_MANAGER' does not exist.

happen when I did commit.

```
entityManager.getTransaction().commit();


@Entity
@Table(name = "S1_MANAGER")
public class manager 
{
    @Id 
    @Column(name = "title_id", length = 128)    
    private String Id;
```

btw, the table also exist in the persistence xml.

Comment: The table exists in `persistence.xml` - but does it also exist in your database?

Comment: how can a table exist in persistence.xml ? there is no place for specifying it there. You mean orm.xml ?

Comment: @Averroes-how should i do that?

Comment: Turn on eclipselink logging to see where you are connecting to and the SQL used as described here: http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Logging make sure you are connecting to the db and schema that has the table.  If that doesn't help, show the log and the persistence.xml and describe how you know the table exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure the table existing on the database for the user/schema you are connecting to.

To have the tables automatically created for you see,

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/DDL